# 1D Convolution with Gaussian Kernel using

Tags: c++, vtk, medical, itk

My goal is to calculate the calculation in each row of a 2D-image ( in the x-direction)
After following the tip from Cory I am trying to use the ‘ConvolutionImageFilter’, and make a kernel with the Gaussian values I calculate before.
I took a look to this example (http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/ImageProcessing/ConvolutionImageFilter) and my question is how to include the values of the Gaussian filter to the kernel, I tried wit the code below and it compiles, but it seems the execution has no end when I update the convolutionFilter… Because of that I think that I am doing something wrong. My code is below and is not so much, if some can give some help I would appreciate that really a lot !!!!.

```
typedef itk::ConvolutionImageFilter <ImageType> ConvFilterType;

ImageType::Pointer kernel = ImageType::New();
CreateKernel(kernel, Gaussian , 256);

//Convolve image with kernel
ConvFilterType::Pointer convolutionFilter = ConvFilterType::New();
convolutionFilter->SetInput(Li_itk);
convolutionFilter->SetImageKernelInput(kernel);
convolutionFilter->Update();

void Reg_image_v2::CreateKernel(Reg_image_v2::ImageType::Pointer kernel, double *Gaussian, unsigned int width) {

ImageType::IndexType start;
start.Fill(0);

ImageType::SizeType size;
    size[0] = width;
size[1] = 1;

ImageType::RegionType region;
region.SetSize(size);
region.SetIndex(start);

kernel->SetRegions(region);
kernel->Allocate();

ImageType::IndexType pixelIndex;
for (int i = 0 ; i < width ; i ++){
    pixelIndex[0] = i ;
    pixelIndex[1] = 0 ;
    kernel->SetPixel(pixelIndex,Gaussian[i]);
}

itk::ImageRegionIterator<ImageType> imageIterator(kernel, region);

while(!imageIterator.IsAtEnd()) 

{
//imageIterator.Set??

++imageIterator; //operator++  increments the iterator one position in the positive direction
}


} // end createKernel
```

Antonio

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the itkGaussianOperator?
http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Operators/GaussianOperator